# Formatting Datetime Index with Pandas DataFrame Styler, to only show time-part

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, formatting, pandas-styles

I'm using the style property of Pandas DataFrames to create HTML tables for emailing.

The issue I am having is that I have **a datetime index that shows up as a datetime stamp when I'd like it to show as a date instead. I'm not interested in the time part**. In the interpreter, the DataFrame does print out correctly (only shows the date part). But when I render after stylizing using the style property of the table, it generates HTML that puts out the time part as well. I've looked into using `style.format()` but I can't access the index column.
I would reset the index in order to make the datetime column a normal column... but my header columns are MultIndex. If I flatten out and don't use indexes the table looks weird.

Unfortunately I found this in the .style documentation:

> ***Limitations***
>
> - DataFrame only (use `Series.to_frame().style`)
> - The index and columns must be unique
> - No large repr, and performance isn’t great; this is intended for summary DataFrames
> - You can only style the values, not the index or columns
> - You can only apply styles, you can’t insert new HTML
>   entities Some of these will be addressed in the future.
>
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Limitations

I'm posting to see if anyone has any ideas for how I can get around this. Thanks!

Example table that shows the issue:
[example_table_link](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aleksarias/78b67b61ca4f0543f5fba4705caf2fd8/raw/f78527a38c650121108161492c779b97af126907/html_sample.html)

Code for generating table:

```
account_day_df = merged[['Day', 'Metric1', 'Metric2', 'Metric3', 'Metric4', 'Campaign type']]
account_day_df = account_day_df.groupby(['Day', 'Campaign type']).sum()
account_day_df.loc[:, 'Metric5'] = account_day_df['Metric1'] / account_day_df['Metric4']
account_day_df = account_day_df.unstack('Campaign type')

html += (
    account_day_df.style
        .background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=['Metric5'])
        .set_table_attributes('border="1" class="dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"')
        .render(i)
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As part of the [Styler enhancements](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#styler) in pandas 1.4.0 [`format_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format_index.html) can now be used to style the index directly:

For Example:

```py
df.style.format_index(lambda s: s.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

[image: styled index]

This can, of course, be chained with other styles:

```py
(
    df.style.format_index(lambda s: s.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        .format(precision=2)
        .background_gradient()
)
```

[image: Styled DataFrame with multiple styles. Formatted index, precision, and background gradient]

---

Setup:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import Generator, MT19937

rng = Generator(MT19937(10))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    rng.random(size=(10, 2)),
    index=pd.date_range('2022-01-01', periods=10, freq='D')
)

df.style
```

[image: Styler object with no formatting]

Answer (score 5):

You can convert your index to `object` instead of `datetime` using `strftime()` by doing `df.index = df.index.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")`. Here's an example:

```
data = np.random.randn(10, 5)
index = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=10, freq='D')
pd.DataFrame(data, index=index).style.format("{:.2}")
```

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame(data, index=index.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")).style.format("{:.2}")
```

[image]

Comment: But how do you do it while preserving my multi-index as in the provided example?

Comment: In your example you have multiindex on the columns. Changing the index does not mess with the columns.